Is there connection between digits of nth prime and natural logarithm?
I started with a small list of primes less than 100 and checked counted its digits then I wonder what will happen for larger values I made a plot for values up to 500,000 for this range the closest function that seems similar is $\frac{ln(x)}{2}+1$ here is the plot:


Well, the prime number theorem says the number of primes numbers less than $N$ is $\approx \frac {N}{\ln N}$ and the number of digits if $N$ is approx $\log_{10} N$ so the number of digits ought to be ... something.
